# Import "undetected_chromedriver" could not be resolved

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

i got this error **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip'**

> `Requirement already satisfied: undetected_chromedriver in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.1.5.post4) Requirement already satisfied: selenium>=4.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (4.4.0) Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (2.28.1) Requirement already satisfied: websockets in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (10.3) Requirement already satisfied: trio~=0.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.21.0) Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.26.11) Requirement already satisfied: trio-websocket~=0.9 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.9.2) Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->undetected_chromedriver) (2022.6.15) Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->undetected_chromedriver) (3.3) Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->undetected_chromedriver) (2.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: outcome in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.2.0) Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (2.4.0) Requirement already satisfied: async-generator>=1.9 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.10) Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (22.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.2.0) Requirement already satisfied: wsproto>=0.14 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (37.0.4) Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=0.14 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (22.0.0) Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,<2.0,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.7.1) Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3.4->urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.15.1) Requirement already satisfied: h11<1,>=0.9.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from wsproto>=0.14->trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.13.0) Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=1.3.4->urllib3[secure,socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver)`
>
> `--- Logging error --- Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1673, in print extend(render(renderable, render_options)) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1305, in render for render_output in iter_render: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in __rich_console__ for line in lines: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/segment.py", line 249, in split_lines for segment in segments: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1283, in render renderable = rich_cast(renderable) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/protocol.py", line 36, in rich_cast renderable = cast_method() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 130, in __rich__ pip_cmd = get_best_invocation_for_this_pip() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 58, in get_best_invocation_for_this_pip if found_executable and os.path.samefile( File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 101, in samefile s2 = os.stat(f2) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip' Call stack: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(main()) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main return command.main(cmd_args) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main return self._main(args) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main self.handle_pip_version_check(options) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 190, in handle_pip_version_check pip_self_version_check(session, options) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 236, in pip_self_version_check logger.warning("[present-rich] %s", upgrade_prompt) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1489, in warning self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1624, in _log self.handle(record) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1634, in handle self.callHandlers(record) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1696, in callHandlers hdlr.handle(record) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 968, in handle self.emit(record) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit self.handleError(record)`

looks like i already have undetected_chromedriver installed as i can see it when i do pip3 list

however i am keeping this error

> `Import "undetected_chromedriver" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports`

Comment: You're trying to install `undetected_chromedriver`?

Comment: haha..For a minute I thought same

Comment: yeah i am trying to install undetected_chromedriver